# Как правильно употреблять $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] в сравнении?

Tags: php

Есть такая конструкция

```
<li <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/index.php" ? 'class="active"' : 'class="none"';?> >Лента</li>
```

На странице index.php `<li>` получает класс "none".

Есть предопределенная функция php console_log, которая выводит в консоль браузера `$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]` как "/index.php".

Экранирование слэша в условии, как и его удаление, не помогает. У кого какие идеи?

Comment: сделайте echo этого `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` непосредственно там, где вы его сравниваете, и проверьте какое значение получаете. все вопрос отпадут, наверное.

Comment: А console_log($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]) чем хуже?

Comment: ключевой вопрос был в том, чтобы вывести непосредственно перед сравнением. Если выводите вы в индексе, а сравниваете в заинклуденном файле, то значение будет другим.

Comment: С этого места поподробней, если можно. Сравнение действительно было в заинклуденном файле, а выводилось в индексе.

Comment: куда тут подробней то, `PHP_SELF` содержит имя (от документ-рута) выполняемого файла в текущий момент, это вроде очевидно из названия. Не вызванного запросом скрипта, а именно того файла, в котором написана эта строка кода.

Comment: `SCRIPT_NAME` будет содержать имя исполняемого (главного) скрипта,  а не текущего.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы усложняете. Если в индексе заинклюдить "funcs.inc", то PHP_SELF выполняемым файлом будет считать именно index.php . Это он нам четко дал понять, когда мы выводили его через echo.

Answer (score 0):

Решилось использованием $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] вместо $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]

```
<li <?php echo $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] == '/index.php' ? 'class="active"' : '';?> >
```

Тем не менее, интересно будет услышать, как ведет себя PHP_SELF в сравнении. Если кто знает, оставьте здесь комментарии.

Comment: кавычки не забудьте добавить.

Comment: Только если у тебя прилетит GET запрос ?xxxx условие не сработает